# Given a .jpg or .png, and a URL, how to generate a "LogoQ" type of QR code?

Tags: java, python, imagemagick, qr-code, graphical-logo

From [www.qrcode.com](http://www.qrcode.com/en/codes/logoq.html), "LogoQ is a new type of QR Code created to enhance visual recognizability by combining it with letters and pictures in full color."

I would like to be able to take an image file and a URL and generate such a QR code, similar to what is offered at website visualead.com -- but without the generated QR code redirecting to their site, and potentially encountering ads, all before the original URL is opened.

Have searched a bit for "LogoQ" but could not find useful results.

I'm open to using Python, Java, or ImageMagick, or whatever other libraries or tools might be suitable for this.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a LogoQ themed QR code is a simple task for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). ImageMagick language bindings cover both [Java](http://www.jmagick.org) and [Python](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/), but I'll give an example with CLI utilities.

For creating a LogoQ, screen [compose](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compose) a logo graphic over a QR code.

```sh
convert /path/to/qr_code.png \
        /path/to/logo.png \
        -compose Screen \
        -composite \
        /path/to/logo_qr.png
```

[image: How to generate a LogoQ QR code]

There are many ways, libraries, and APIs to generate a QR code. I half remember [Google providing a free API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes), but that's been deprecated.
If you've compiled ImageMagick with HTTP support, then update the above example to call web services directly over HTTP

```sh
convert https://example.org/path/to/qr/api \
        https://example.org/path/to/cdn/logo \
        -compose Screen \
        -composite \
        /path/to/logo_qr.png
```

[image: LogoQ QRcode web service]